# Как получить DATE из строки без разделителей?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

Есть строка такого формата `20140102125832`.

Как наиболее идиоматично красиво получить тип `DATE` из этой строки?

Ввод: `20140102125832`

Вывод: `2014-01-02 12:58:32`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with str (val) as (
    select '20140102125832' from dual),
dt (val) as (
    select cast (str.val as date, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') from str)
select to_char (dt.val, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') str, dump (dt.val, 16) dump from dt
/

STR                 DUMP                            
------------------- --------------------------------
2014-01-02 12:58:32 Typ=13 Len=8: de,7,1,2,c,3a,20,0
```

Не следует забывать, что колонка с типом `date` в результате выборки может быть в клиенте неявно преобразована обратно в символьный вид, в соответствии с параметром сессии, который можно узнать так:

```
select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter='NLS_DATE_FORMAT'
/

PARAMETER                      VALUE                           
------------------------------ --------------------------------
NLS_DATE_FORMAT                YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS
```

Чтобы избежать неявного преобразования, следует в выборке, используя функцию `to_char`, явно преобразовать обратно в символьный вид.

Answer (score 1):

на клиенте стоял другой формат даты, поэтому показывало при выборке дату без времени, можно изменить формат на клиенте навсегда или на одну сессию

```
select
  to_date('20140102125832', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as dt
from dual;
```

результат: `2014-01-02 12:58:32`

формат поменял на одну сессию:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

Comment: А зачем вы указали разделители в формате даты/времени? Почему не 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'

Comment: @MaxU имеете в виду в фии `to_date`?